# sql cte distinct count

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, common-table-expression

I want to add the total number of products of the brand to the total column.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2d00a/1

this my query;

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM category 
    WHERE id = 1 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT c.id 
    FROM category c, cte 
    WHERE c.parentid = cte.id
), cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT brandid, d.catid 
    FROM products d, cte 
    WHERE d.catid = cte.id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT u.brandid, COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) 
    FROM products u, cte 
    WHERE catid = cte.id
    GROUP BY brandid
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    brandid, logo, brand, id, id as total 
FROM
    brand, cte2 
WHERE 
    id = cte2.brandid 
ORDER BY 
    brand ASC
```

Comment: Why are you still using that ancient 31 year old syntax? It's long past time to start using the "newer" 28 year old JOIN syntax.[Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: sorry, i can't working inner join in  this query

Comment: yes, my question :  want to add the total number of products of the brand to the total column.

Comment: *"i can't working inner join in this query"* Well, switch to an explicit Join, and not that 1980's syntax, and you'll likely have more success.

Comment: this query : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2d00a/1

please, run inner join ?

Comment: If it's a different query, it should be in the question, @dfred . Not off site.

Comment: Please update your question with the sample data from your fiddle and the add _the expected output_. Also, your `cte2` combines calculated values from `count(distinct u.id)` with ID values from `d.catid` and columns `brandid` and `id` in your final selection contain the same data. Do you perhaps need separate category and product counts for each brand? Or separate brand and product counts for each category? If so, please put that in the question.

Comment: i want to total number products of the brand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.logo,
       b.brand,
       count(p.id) total
FROM brand b
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.brandid = b.id
GROUP BY b.id, b.logo, b.brand
```

Assuming you want to filter products based on category 1 (where you include the subcategories as well)

```
WITH categories_and_subcategories AS (
   SELECT id FROM category 
   WHERE id = 1 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT c.id 
   FROM category c 
   INNER JOIN categories_and_subcategories cs 
         ON c.parentid = cs.id),
filtered_products AS (
   SELECT p.id,
          p.name,
          p.catid,
          p.brandid 
   FROM products p
   INNER JOIN categories_and_subcategories c
         ON p.catid = c.id
   )
SELECT b.id,
       b.logo,
       b.brand,
       count(p.id) total
FROM brand b
LEFT JOIN filtered_products p ON p.brandid = b.id
GROUP BY b.id, b.logo, b.brand
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Query as per my Understanding to get the total products per brand. [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1bddaeffc0b8b1df7d4c44ada2f7f035) working code

```
CREATE TABLE brand (
    [id] INT
    ,[brand] VARCHAR(13)
    ,[logo] VARCHAR(13)
    );

INSERT INTO brand ([id], [brand], [logo])
VALUES ('1', 'samsung', 'logo.jpg');

CREATE TABLE products (
    [id] INT
    ,[name] VARCHAR(13)
    ,[catid] INT
    ,[brandid] INT
    );

INSERT INTO products ([id], [name], [catid], [brandid])
VALUES ('1', 'samsung tv', '2', '1')
    ,('1', 'samsung2 tv', '2', '1')

SELECT b.Id
    ,b.brand
    ,b.logo
    ,p.Id
    ,COUNT(1) [total]
FROM brand b
INNER JOIN products p ON b.Id = p.brandId
GROUP BY b.Id
    ,b.brand
    ,b.logo
    ,p.Id
```

Results:

[image]